# Join tables based on the output of select query

Tags: sqlite

I tried the following but got the wrong result back.

```
select tab_2.id_3,tab_2.name from tab_2 where tab_2.id_3 in (select id_1 from tab_1 where id_1= id_2)
```

**What I'm looking for is:**

I have the first table where I extracted the ids I want:

```
tab_1:
id_1 | id_2
ab01 | ab01
ab02 | ab02
ab03 | ab05
ab04 | ab09

Select id_1 from tab_1 where id_1= id_2
--id_1--
ab01
ab02

tab_2
id_3|name
ab01|test
ab02|test
ab07|test
ab06|test
```

**Expected join result from tab_1 & tab_2**

```
id_1 | id_3 | name
ab01 | ab01 | test
ab02 | ab02 | test
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem I had was the output. In one table the IDs were capital and in the second table IDs were lower case. So I converted one of them to either lower case or capital.

lower(ids)
upper(ids)

[Pictorial Presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ig8e.gif)

```
select tab_2.id_3,tab_2.name from tab_2 where tab_2.id_3 in (select id_1 from tab_1 where id_1= id_2)
```

Comment: Your query is not fine as you can see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqW6xhFkFyFpsgbbtggAbh/0 It does not return the expected results that you posted. Also your query would not even run in other databases, check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqW6xhFkFyFpsgbbtggAbh/1 because your subquery returns more than 1 rows and it can't be used with `=`. Check the demo in my answer to see why that my query returns your expected results.

Comment: beside the = I used in and adjusted the first columns I selected. But as I said, output was case sensitive which was the main problem for me.

Comment: You get 4 rows as results as opposed to 2 rows that you want.

Comment: two rows only is my output. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqW6xhFkFyFpsgbbtggAbh/3

Comment: Press the button RUN in the fiddle. The result is **4 rows** all having id_3 = 'ab01'

Comment: did you see the updated link? i wasn't saving the query that's why you were seeing the old results.

Comment: Yes now I see the updated link. So you prefer an old style join (because this is what the comma between the table names is) based on a subquery than a proper join with an ON clause? If you do fine. But read this: https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/finding-code-smells-using-sql-prompt-old-style-join-syntax-st001 and this: https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/old-join-syntax-vs-new

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and apply the condition in the `where` clause:

```
select t1.id_1, t2.id_3, t2.name 
from tab_1 t1 inner join tab_2 t2
on t2.id_3 = t1.id_1 
where t1.id_1 = t1.id_2
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iqW6xhFkFyFpsgbbtggAbh/2).
Results:

```
| id_1 | id_3 | name |
| ---- | ---- | ---- |
| ab01 | ab01 | test |
| ab02 | ab02 | test |
```

Comment: Thanks forpas. But this is a simple join and not a join with a sub-query. in my case, I had to join based on a specific output and using where condition only wouldn't help.